# How to type full multilinear product symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image: symbol graph]

I want to know how to type the symbol above in LaTeX, thanks!

Comment: $[\![  ]\!]$ is ok.

Comment: [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a useful thing to know about!

Comment: Is the symbol used like, say, +? That is, like a binary operation symbol?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ stmaryrd }
\begin{document}

with \verb+stmaryrd+ package : $ \rrbracket$

\end{document}
```